# Palindrome in java

Tags: java, string, palindrome

Here what I tried
sample input is "aabaa"
eg: in if condition val[0] = a[4]
if it is equal i stored it in counter variable if it is  half of the length it original string it is palindrome
if it is not it is not a palindrome

I tried with my basic knowledge in java if there is any errors let me know

```
boolean solution(String inputString) {
  int val = inputString.length();
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<inputString.length(); i++) {
    if(inputString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(val-i)) {
       count = count++;
      if (count>0) {
        return true;
      }  
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: count++ is sufficient . you dont need 'count = count++', read the java language documentation.

Comment: Both `return` statement return `true`, which means this method always returns `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String text) {
    String clean = text.replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase();
    int length = clean.length();
    int forward = 0;
    int backward = length - 1;
    while (backward > forward) {
        char forwardChar = clean.charAt(forward++);
        char backwardChar = clean.charAt(backward--);
        if (forwardChar != backwardChar)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

From [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-palindrome)

Answer (score 1):

In your version you compare first element with last, second with second last etc.
last element in this case is inputString.length()-1(so need to use 'inputString.charAt(val-i-1)' . If you iterate till end, then the count should be equal to length of the string.

```
for(int i = 0; i<inputString.length(); i++){
   if(inputString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(val-i-1)){
       count ++;
   }
 }
 return (count==val); //true when count=val
```

Or alternatlively iterate till the mid point of the array, then count value is val/2.

```
for(int i = 0; i<inputString.length()/2; i++){
   if(inputString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(val-i-1)){
       count ++;
   }
 }
 return (count==val/2);  //true when count=val/2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no constraints in the question so let me throw in a more cheesy solution.

```java
boolean isPalindrome(String in) 
    final String inl = in.toLowerCase();
    return new StringBuilder(inl).reverse().toString().equals(inl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a word, sentence, verse, or even a number that reads the same forward and backward. In this java solution, we’ll see how to figure out whether the number or the string is palindrome in nature or not.

Method - 1

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "Nitin", revStr = "";
    
    int strLen = str.length();

    for (int i = (strLen - 1); i >=0; --i) {
      revStr = revStr + str.charAt(i);
    }

    if (str.toLowerCase().equals(revStr.toLowerCase())) {
      System.out.println(str + " is a Palindrome String.");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(str + " is not a Palindrome String.");
    }
```

Method - 2

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int n = 3553, revNum = 0, rem;
    
    // store the number to the original number
    int orgNum = n;
    
    /* get the reverse of original number
    store it in variable */
    while (n != 0) {
      remainder = n % 10;
      revNum = revNum * 10 + rem;
      n /= 10;
    }
    
    // check if reversed number and original number are equal
    if (orgNum == revNum) {
      System.out.println(orgNum + " is Palindrome.");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(orgNum + " is not Palindrome.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily with Stringbuilder/StringBuffer

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("madam");
 
 if(sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString()))
 System.out.println("Palindrome");
 else
 System.out.println("Not Palindrome");

}
```

}